# Excel pivot table one column per dimension

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

How can I add multiple fields to the "row" area of a pivot table and have them show up as distinct columns on the pivot table instead of nested under one column only? I essentially need the pivot table to look like a standard table to I may do VLOOKUPS on several fields.

The pivot table below shows what I do not want. Instead, I'd like Field1 and Field2 to remain two columns:

[image]

Comment: A PivotTable may not be the solution you're looking for. The whole idea of a PivotTable is to group data at several levels. Why are you using a PivotTable - what's the end goal of the overall process?

Comment: @Werrf I need to summarize several fields, sorry the minimum viable example I included does not show that. My actual data has 5+ categorical fields and 10+ numerical variables.

Comment: Are you going to have multiple Marks, or multiple Firefighters, or both, or neither? If there's a 1:1 matchup of names to roles, you don't need to include both values in the PivotTable - you can just use whatever unique identifier you have and group by that. If the idea is to create a matrix-type data set, you may have more luck with formulae than Pivots.

Comment: The data has multiple observations for each Field1 Field2 combination because of additional fields in the data set.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want, since Field1 and Field2 are *already* in two separate columns in the screenshot you provided. Can you manually create a table with a small set of the desired results and share that in addition to a small amount of input data? I don't have a good sense of how you want to structure the output.

Comment: @allquixotic I need Field1 and Field2 to be in two separate columns in the pivot table. Picture shows both the original data and the pivot.

Comment: I understand that there's extra data that we're not seeing; my question is whether you really need BOTH Field1 and Field2 in the Pivot.

Comment: @Werrf yes, absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say again what I advised in a comment above - it doesn't sound like a PivotTable is really what you're looking for. However, you can get something like what you're describing by changing the PivotTable layout.

1. Click a cell inside your PivotTable to activate the **PivotTable tools** tabs
2. Go to the **Design** tab
3. On the left of the ribbon, look for **Report Layout**. Click it to open the dropdown menu.
4. In the dropdown, you'll want two options: *Show in Tabular Form* and *Repeat All Item Labels*

This will create the structure you describe, with each label in a different column.

Answer (score 0):

With any cell in the pivot table highlighted, go to the Pivot Table Design tab and choose either "Outline" or "Tabular" formats under "Report Layout".

[image: Pivot Table > Design > Report Layout]