# How to get values in right column of pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have employee information in form of table. There are columns Emp ID, Name, Address, Email etc.

When I am inserting pivot table on this table. I am getting Emp Name in a row below Emp ID.

I tried dragging Emp ID in Rows and Emp Name in Values but it is only giving me either count or Sum, not actual value.

How can I get it in front of of Emp ID i.e. Emp ID in `Col1` and Emp Name in `Col2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel pivot table one column per dimension](https://superuser.com/questions/1161774/excel-pivot-table-one-column-per-dimension)

Comment: You are getting `Name` below `ID` because You may have selected both for the ROW in Pivot Table. You may put one column in Row(ID) one in Column(Name) and if  you have Numeric Column the put it to Values. ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First access the field settings for the fields you put in the ROWS section.

[image]

Then in the totals option, choose `none`.

[image]

Finally on the layout and print section, choose `show items in tabular form`

[image]

Do this for each field.